How can I add external application bundle in my Tauri app
I'm using Tauri with SvelteKit and I want to include a external application to install with my Tuari app.
Here's a quick pass on app flow:

Download and install Tuari app on our system. This will include installation of a external app [Mechdyne TGX Receiver (VDI client)] and my Tuari App

I'm trying to include external application to my Tuari app bundle

You're looking to do sidecar loading.
Here's an example configuration:
{
  "tauri": {
    "bundle": {
      "externalBin": [
        "/absolute/path/to/sidecar",
        "relative/path/to/binary",
        "binaries/my-sidecar"
      ]
    },
    "allowlist": {
      "shell": {
        "sidecar": true,
        "scope": [
          { "name": "/absolute/path/to/sidecar", "sidecar": true },
          { "name": "relative/path/to/binary", "sidecar": true },
          { "name": "binaries/my-sidecar", "sidecar": true }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Depending on the target system (mac or win) and distribution method (app store or not), you might want to configure how you sign your bundle differently, assuming this third party software is already signed by a vendor.

but getting error:
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: /Users/gulamgaus/Desktop/development/spark/src-tauri/target/release/build/app-917c8c7b6097ff38/build-script-build (exit status: 1)
--- stdout
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TAURI_CONFIG
cargo:rerun-if-changed=tauri.conf.json
cargo:rustc-cfg=desktop
path matching ./external-bundles/TGX_Mac_Installer-aarch64-apple-darwin not found.
Error failed to build app: failed to build app

@GulamGaus can you share minimum reproducible example on github?
